# Dictionary in Swift Not giving Correct Response

Tags: iphone, swift, swift2

I need a response of Dictionary in {} but they give in form[]. Please help. Here is my code

```
 func getRequestObject() -> Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
        var requestObject = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
        requestObject["username"] = "a"
        requestObject["password"] = "a"
        return requestObject
    }
```

They give me response like

```
["password": a, "username": a]
```

But I need response

```
{"password": a, "username": a}
```

Comment: Square brackets is the new syntax for representing dictionary in Swift: [key type: value type]

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your Dictionary to json formate like this way:

```
do
{
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(someDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue:0))

        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String

        print(jsonString)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: Note that in Swift 2, you have to use try/catch for the error handling.

Comment: I didn't know that the OP wants JSON format until I see this answer!

Comment: if let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &error)

Comment: @bhumika JSON means JavaScript Object Notation. If the guy would like object in JSON textual representation, than he would like to see  {"password": "a", "username": "a" }. {"password": a, "username": a} is not valid JSON. In JSON, String is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters. Strings are delimited with double-quotation marks and support a backslash escaping syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
    if let jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(getRequestObject(), options: [])
    {
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String

        print(jsonString)
    }
```

Output

```
{"password": "a", "username": "a"}
```

The quotes around "a" is because the type is string. If you don't need quotes, try another quick alternative as below:

```
    var myString = getRequestObject().description
    let myRange = myString.startIndex..<myString.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
    myString.replaceRange(myRange, with: "{")
    let myRange2 = myString.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)..<myString.endIndex
    myString.replaceRange(myRange2, with: "}")
    print(myString)
```

Comment: print it, and please compare with wanted {"password": a, "username": a}. and let us know the result!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in the standard library of Swift have the following syntax:

```
let dict = [key : value, key : value, ...]

// in your case probably
let dict = getRequestObject()
```

And printing or converting them to a `String` results in the same format: `[...]`

For a format with curly braces you can cast the dictionary to a `NSDictionary`

```
let dict2 = dict as NSDictionary

// both result in "{key : value, key : value, ...}"
String(dict2)
print(dict2)
```